# How can I add my Map<String, Integer > from my @Controller to the google api pie chart using thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf, google-visualization

I have a problem I don't know how to add my Map with datas from my db to the google.visualization.arrayToDataTable in the Thymeleaf template.

I succeeded to show  the map in the view with the console log but my problem is how to add it to the google.visualization.arrayToDataTable.

This is my code from @Controller

```
  @GetMapping("/pourcentageAges")
  public String ageDesClients(Model model){

    Map<String,Integer>listeAgesTranches = 
    utilisateurMetier.agesClientsClub();
    System.out.println("je suis la tailme de la liste 
    "+listeAgesTranches.size());


    model.addAttribute("liste",listeAgesTranches);
    model.addAttribute("tailleListe",listeAgesTranches.size());

    return "utilisateur/agePourcentage";
}
```

And this is my code from my view:
So I repeat I need just to assign the " var ageList" to the google.visualization.arrayToDataTable

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript" >
// Load google charts
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);



/*<![CDATA[*/
var ageList=new Map();
var tailleListe= /*[[${tailleListe}]]*/

ageList= /*[[${liste}]]*/ 'default';





/*]]>*/

// Draw the chart and set the chart values


// for (i=0; i<tailleListe;i++){
//     console.log('je suis la'+[Object.keys(message)[i],Object.values(message)[i]])
// }

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Task', 'ages between 16 and 90 group by 10'],
        ['age betweeen 20-30',5 ]

    ]);

    // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
    var options = {'title':'Ages en pourcent de 16 a 90 ans', 'width':550, 
   'height':400,is3D: true};

    // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
    var chart = new 
    google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
     }
     </script>
```

Thank you a lot for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

first, create a new array before using `arrayToDataTable`
then you can use the `concat` method to combine the column headings with `ageList`
then pass the new array to `arrayToDataTable`

try it like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript" >
// Load google charts
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

/*<![CDATA[*/
var ageList=new Map();
var tailleListe= /*[[${tailleListe}]]*/

ageList= /*[[${liste}]]*/ 'default';

/*]]>*/

function drawChart() {
  var dataArray = [
    ['Task', 'ages between 16 and 90 group by 10']
  ];
  dataArray = dataArray.concat(ageList);
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);

  // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
  var options = {'title':'Ages en pourcent de 16 a 90 ans', 'width':550, 'height':400,is3D: true};

  // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank for your help , but when i tried your soluton a have a problem with the concat

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
    at drawChart (pourcentageAges:46)

Comment: sounds like `dataArray` is undefined, will you please edit the question with the latest version of your code?